# Using tf.train.Supervisor's default summary_op on validation data?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm fitting a classifier that has two placeholders, one for my input features and one for my output labels. To get data into the graph I'm placing a ndarray into a feed_dict. How can I use a `tf.train.Supervisor` to evaluate the model on validation data without having to evaluate the `summary_op` manually? Is it only possible by using readers instead of feed_dicts?

This is my current workaround, where I'm checking elapsed time and manually evaluating the `summary_op`:

```py
import time

import tensorflow as tf

t = time.time()
summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir="tensorboard/my-run", summary_op=None)
with sv.managed_session() as sess:
    for data in training_data:

        # Fit training data.
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={'input:0': data[0], 'output:0': data[1]})

        # Evaluate on validation data.
        if time.time() - t > 60.0:
            t = time.time()
            data = next(validation_data)
            summary = sess.run(summary_op, feed_dict={'input:0': data[0], 'output:0': data[1]})
            sv.summary_computed(sess, summary)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT: tf.train.Supervisor will probably be deprecated, so nevermind. See [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6604#issuecomment-270950324) comment.**

One thing that's *slightly* cleaner is to use `tf.train.Supervisor.loop` instead of checking elapsed time manually.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir="tensorboard/my-run", summary_op=None)
with sv.managed_session() as sess:
    sv.loop(60, lambda: sv.summary_computed(sess, sess.run(summary_op, feed_dict=next(validation_data))))
    for data in training_data:
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict=data)
```

Comment: Good to know that more people have this problem :) I moved to using the batch tensor from the input queue directly.

Answer (score -1):

You can use your workaround. That should work.

Sherry